# NoMethodError in Shop#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am getting an error when I try to add a barber to my database.

I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Shop#new
Showing /Users/Augus/Rails/Barbershop/app/views/shop/new.html.erb where line #3 raised:
undefined method `barbers_path' for #<#<Class:0x105e7b818>:0x105bfe360>
Extracted source (around line #3):

1: <H1>New barber</H1>
2: 
3: <%= form_for @barber do |f| %>
4:  <%= f.text_field :name %> <br />
5:  <%= f.submit %>
6: <% end %>
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

My shop_controller.rb:

```
  def new
    @barber = Barber.new
  end
```

My view new.html.erb:

```
<H1>New barber</H1>

<%= form_for @barber do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %> <br />
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', shop_path %>
```

I also get this in my routes:

```
  resources :shop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Rails tries to figure out the path for sending forms based on the object you pass in. In your case Rails tries to build path for sending the form based on your `@barber` object. As your `routes.rb` shows, you haven't written `resources :barbers` and your form fails to find proper path. You have to specify your path directly. Like this way:

```
<%= form_for @barber, url: shop_path do |f| %>
```

Comment: Check routes before use . Run 'rake routes' console .

Comment: This gives an other error: compile error
/Users/Augus/Rails/Barbershop/app/views/shop/new.html.erb:3: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting kEND

Comment: I guess you are under Ruby 1.8.7. Try to replace parameter this way: `:url => shop_path`

Comment: Also, you may want to add `:as => :shop` to the call, but that depends whether your `create` action is expecting `params[:shop]` or `params[:barber]`.

Comment: Yea i am, but when i try that i get an Routes error: No route matches {:controller=>"shop", :action=>"show"}

Comment: Change it to `:url => shops_path` (with an 's').

Comment: If you've got `No route matches {:controller=>"shop", :action=>"show"}` then your item was created and now Rails tries to display it. Go to your `views/shop/` and create here `show.htm.erb`.

Comment: @jdoe, no it's a problem in the routing, so that won't help (yet). I think you might have to pass the url as a hash: `:url => {:action => :create}`.

Comment: @tsherif I think the opposite: routing has nothing to do with it. But also I think your response would be more helpful if it was mad in the author's question. I doubt he'll get notification for it.

Comment: The error is a `RoutingError`, so I'm pretty sure routing has something to do with it. I think he'll get notification just by being in the thread, but just in case: @Augus1986.

Comment: I guess we miss something small here. Or it's just we've got an app that needs to be restarted. There is no way that `resources :shop` didn't create routes for show. It's time to ask the author again to show us his `rake routes` output.

Comment: Alright this was kinda the problem, Though i just renamed my controllers to let this work normaly. So the main problem was in my naming for the controllers and models. But thanks for your time.

Comment: It was a good lesson for you: follow the convention. Name your resources in plural: resource*s*, :shop*s*, Shop*s*Controller, shop*s* table and you'll be fine )

Answer (score 1):

When you submit a new record form, the function controller#create is called. controller#new is the function that generates the page containing the form.

You need a BarberController with #create method.

Create the resource like this:

> `resources :shop do`
>
> > `resources :barber`
>
> `end`

A shop contains barbers.

Then `form_for [@shop, @barber], :action => 'create'` will trigger `BarberController#create` the last line of which should probably redirect to `shop`.

Comment: Yea, but I also got an #create, but this error comes when i even try to go to the page with the form. So i can't even submit it.

Comment: I did not read your question properly, please check my new answer.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of:

```
<%= form_for @barber do |f| %>
```

Try this:

```
<%= form_for(@barber) do |f| %>
```